Rails attachment delegation to another model optionally
I have two models InInvoice, Disbursement. Both are associated: InInvoice optionally belongs_to disbursement. Both have a has_one attachment called att.
InInvoice is supposed to delegate att calls to Disbursement but only if att is NOT present on the InInvoice? (else the att is used normally on the InInvoice).
Optional delegation seems not to work which I thought about first.
Basically I am getting a "Step level to deep"/endless loop if I try to create a deviated method def att  which calls the attachment but via the method att.
Basically what I think to need is a return value of the rails attachment in the method which doesn't use the method name itself. Is there something like: File.new(att_attribute) which can be called in in the att method?

Add a new method to InInvoice called working_att -- return the InInvoice att if present otherwise return the att from Disbursement.

Are you talking about ActiveStorage attachments here? Can you include an example of the models?
